# Trouble loading Node Azure Functions locally on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, azure-functions-core-tools

I am building a Static Web App using Node functions for an API. Everything works when deployed to Azure, but I cannot run locally on Mac. I am able to run locally on Windows. I am using the new v4 programming model, using this pattern:

```
app.http('my-cool-func', {
    route: "my/cool/route",
    methods: ['GET'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request: HttpRequest): Promise<HttpResponseInit> => {
        ...
    }
});
```

On Windows, when I punch in:

```bash
func --version
```

I get: `4.0.5441`. When I kick off my /api folder directly with `func start`, it identifies the functions correctly and all is well.

On Mac, when I ask for the func version, I get `4.0.3971`. I installed it using brew (following [these directions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools#installing)):

```bash
brew tap azure/functions
brew install azure-functions-core-tools@4
```

However, according to [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-typescript?tabs=macos%2Cazure-cli%2Cbrowser&pivots=nodejs-model-v4), which also provides the exact same installation instructions:

```text
Make sure you install version v4.0.5382 of the Core Tools, or a later version.
```

This note is only present when that article is set to `v4` mode; it disappears when setting it to `v3` mode. One presumes that some glitch has been fixed between here and there, and that the glitch is relevant only for v4-mode implementations. Perhaps something to do with detecting the presence of functions?

Anyway, upon kicking off the same /api folder with `func start` on the Mac, I receive the unfortunately familiar message:

```text
No job functions found. Try making your job classes and methods public. If you're using binding extensions ... etc.
```

Is there an updated version of the Azure Functions Core Tools I can get my hands on for Mac? How can I install it, if not using brew?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the `v4` Programming Model like you suspected. Based on [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=javascript%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v4#supported-versions), you need a host runtime of at least `4.25` which is available in version `4.0.5357` of Azure Functions Core Tools onwards.

I don't have a mac to try out the homebrew install but you should be able to download a newer release from the [releases pages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/releases) directly for now.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get my hands on the zip file, but extracting it and running it is giving me problems. First, I was able to make `func` executable with a `chmod` command, but then I started getting all kinds of grief like `'/Users/me/tools/Azure.Functions.Cli.osx-x64.4.0.5455/libcoreclr.dylib' not valid for use in process: library load disallowed by system policy)` which when researched has to do with code signing? ugh. Any advice on installing this?